# iTunes Connect: Can't save app information after uploading new binary

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, organizer

I'm trying to upload an iOS app for review using Xcode's Organizer and I've encountered two problems:

**Case 1**

Binary uploads but when I press *Submit for Review* iTunes Connect gives the error:

> Your app information could not be saved. Try again. If the problem
>   persists, contact us.

**Case 2**

After getting the first error message, I tried uploading a new binary, but got the following error message in Organizer:

> ERROR ITMS-9000: "Redundant Binary Upload. There already exists a
>   binary upload with build version '1.1' for train '1.1'"

---

I tried uploading other binaries changing the version number but still I can't get my app to go in the review state. I also can't see any way to delete old binaries that were uploaded.

Another observation: My app should be around 30MB but when I look at the uploaded binary it is only 1.46MB. I guess there might be something wrong from the binary but I've built it using the same technique several times before and never had any issues.

Any ideas?

Comment: are u uploading your app first time ?

Comment: I've gotten the same problem since Apple launched the new version of iTunes Connect.

Comment: I have same problem, the binary is not for first time and is an update.

Comment: Yes, I'm uploading this app for the first time. As far as I can tell, I've entered all the info and the same upload procedure worked fine for other apps. I think it might be a (big) bug in the new version of iTunes Connect.

Comment: Actually,error occurred on request URL -https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/apps/702692335/version/submit/start when I clicked on "Submit for Review" and Said "Your app information could not be saved. Try again. If the problem persists, contact us."

Comment: I've just re-login and it fixed my issue.

Comment: None of the answers are work for me. So, I just change the System... And It's Work for me...

Comment: Has anyone noticed that Google is still the only company that can use Javascript in a website and have it just goddamn work?

Comment: @WilliamEntriken very true, iTunes connect is a slow and unstable piece of software and I expect more from Apple

Answer (score 63):

For me, I was filling out the form in Safari and getting the error. I logged out, then switched to Chrome and signed in. This fixed the error, and I was able to submit.

Comment: I switched from Chrome to Safari and that worked! Thx!

Comment: In my case, it is worked in safari and not in chrome. Thanks for giving this answer.

Comment: I was able to open an Incognito Window in Chrome to work around the issue.

Comment: I just logged out and logged in again. That solved it for me.

Comment: for me in Firefox, I just logout and login again. At first turn It gave me error that I need to accept an agreement update. My be due to this cycle the real process of uploading interrupts. Logging out an signin again worked.

Comment: Yep, that did it. Bizarre.

Answer (score 17):

Sign out and Sign In again should work as it worked for me!

Answer (score 9):

I solved this by increasing the number in **Build** (Select the Target, then Xcode -> General -> Build, see picture) by adding **.1** so the build was `3.75` -> `3.75.1`. 
 But only for the Build, the Version is still `3.75` and also appears like that in iTunesConnect.

[image: Showing where to set the Build Version in XCode]

Then the new binary uploaded and I could select it for review. In the picture below you may see the old and the new binary listed in iTunesConnect. Then I finally just had to select the new binary and submit for review.
[image: Showing list of binaries in iTunesConnect]

Comment: Tried, problem still exist.

Comment: @Geaka you need to select the binary and save before submitting. It´s also helpful to explain what you tried and what failed.

Comment: I followed every your steps,of course I saved before submit(Can not submit if not saved),maybe the only thing different with yours is that my app is a new app, first time submit.

Comment: @Geaka For a new App, double check you have all info filled in. But why do you say that you have built it several times before? The size for me was also low. Apple compares the changes between previous App and only updates changed files in the build.

Comment: I created a new app in iTC, then built and uploaded the new app(version 1.0), meet the same errors when submit to review.Then I found this answer, so I built a new build versin 1.0.1,upload and submit to review, the errors still exist.

Answer (score 8):

Open web inspector, you will find that Apple said: `We've got a server error ... 500`
That's the real reason. :)

Update:

Inspired by @phantom, I try to use [dotjs](https://github.com/defunkt/dotjs) to run a javascript script to auto click submit button per 15 seconds, but still get the 500 error all the time.

@Geaka's answer is working for me. Because my product name is Chinese，I change my product name to english(DO NOT include whitespace! It maybe causes another error on building path error.)

I debug the apple website and find a js script named `submit_for_review_cntrl.js` which controls the whole submit progress. From line 123 to line 129(formatted by `{}` button in chrome) that setting the http headers, there is a field named `X-Original-Filename`, the value is given by `$scope.addCcatFileToJson` method in line 138, the param of this method is given by ajax callback, i guess there's a bug for encoding the product name field of the back-end code.

Comment: I saw this too.  I tried resubmitting a few times and it eventually went through.

Comment: @phantom is your app name in English?

Comment: @ptgamr It's in English so that wasn't the problem for me.  It seems there might be more than one issue here.

Comment: In debugging, I see that the URL https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/apps/995732766/versions/814262237/submit/summary is returning the error "Failure running store submission validations"

Answer (score 6):

WTF Apple!

We just solved our version of the problem (generic error message)...

After hitting submit for review I was trying to upload a file for the ERN since my app uses encryption. It finally worked when I used a zip file that contains an image of the ERN response and a txt file describing what encryption is being used.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I also had the issue and was submitting the ERN.  I had tried JPG, PNG, and DOC and all appeared to work fine.  I then tried the ZIP as you mentioned and was able to get past the generic error.  They have really done a bad job with bugs and the new site.

Comment: What a joke! So glad I found your answer -- this worked for me as well. It's odd as Apple throws a 500 error if the ERN doc is not a zip file (check your JS console), but apparently zipping up the ERN doc is the way to go.

Answer (score 6):

The problem unfortunately still occurs. My solution when this happens is removing the binary, clicking on the save button then adding the binary again. Then save and follow the standart procedure. That solves the problem for me without changing the build version or doing anything extra.

Answer (score 3):

Finally find the solution:

Steps:

1. If your app version and build version is 1.0, keep version 1.0 and change build version as 1.1(bigger than last build version), then upload it.
   If your app name is English, choose this build and submit to review, it would be change to review.
2. If your app name is **not English**, Chinese for example, you need to name it in **Bundle display name**,
   **Do not name it in TARGETS directly**.

Maybe is also works for Japanese and Korean.

Comment: Thanks. I'm gonna try this. Just uploaded a new binary with a bigger build version using Organizer. The build validated and uploaded fine. When I look under the Prerelease section in iTC it seems to be uploaded (state = "Uploaded") but I still can't select the build. Will keep waiting...

Comment: Could finally select the build but the problem still exists. I can select the build but when I click "Submit for Review" I get the error "Your app information could not be saved. Try again. If the problem persists, contact us." I've tried contacting Apple but they said it will take several days!

Comment: Looking at the web inspector I see that it's throwing: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: @rayg is your app's name in English?

Comment: I've named the app directly in the Bundle Display Name.

Comment: @rayg Then your TARGETS using English name? If it is, I have no idea yet, I think maybe it is using Japanese somewhere,check carefully.

Comment: Doesn't work for me too. I've tried to submitted many times, but same error

Comment: This worked for me. thank you it was 2 days that i have been working on this error. my app name was persian and as you said I changed to something in english and change bundle display name in info.plist to correct persian name. Then made a build and sent to itunes. select it for build and submit for review.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by switching over to Chrome instead of using Safari.  Presto, worked right away!

Comment: Solved by switched to Safari instead of Chrome

Answer (score 2):

I have met this problem this morning and have solved it. I change my product name from Chinese to English, and write the Chinese name in the Bundle display name, which solve this problem.
You can change the Bundle display name in the info.plist, and change the product name in the General tab in the project.

Answer (score 2):

that's an erratic error. Probably some apple infrastructure problems You may have done something and then it worked - switching your browser, increasing build numbers and the like. But you could've hit several times submit as well. At least, after a while, my submission has been successful.

Comment: I'd login from another computer.

Comment: I thought this guy was joking but i simply just keep clicking submit to see if it works...it did. I changed  nothing....WTF

Answer (score 2):

I opened the iTunes connect on my iPhone , and was able to submit sucessfully via iOS safari. I don't know why.

Comment: Mac Safari also works! I was trying with Google Chrome on Mac, only worked with Safari. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change the Build version. Create 1.2 build for version 1.1 of your app. Then upload your binary. After few minutes (on processing) you'll find new build to submit for rewiew.

I spent 2 hours !!!

Answer (score 1):

Finally, i found the solutions. The main culprits is your PRODUCT NAME, it must be in English!

1. Go to build setting --> packaging --> change your product name into English
2. Change your "BUndle Display Name" to your desire localized name
3. Increase your build version and re-upload

This time you're fine!!!

Comment: Perfect! You saved my and my clients day:)

Answer (score 1):

I was plagued with these errors over and over when adding new screenshots.
Nothing seemed to help.

Then I visited iTunes connect in Safari (I normally use Chrome) and somehow all errors went away.
Maybe related to a Chrome browser extension like AdBlock?

TLDR; use Safari for iTunes Connect

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this submitting an update today to my app. For about 30 minutes I retried and received the same error. I tried, removing the binary, signing out, I also rebuilt the binary with an incremented "Bundle Version String".

None of these steps made any difference, but I continued to retry, continued to get the same error, and eventually it accepted the submission.

I don't believe any of these solutions I tried made any difference. I believe there was some internal error on itunesconnect.  As the message suggests, I think all you should do is try again later...

Answer (score 1):

I only need to clear all my cookies, instead of switching browser.

Answer (score 1):

Switch the browser you are using & then remove the build, save that once & then again add the build to it & then again save it. After that click on submit for review & it will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

After 3 day, Itunes accept my first binary. I have tried to change my Bundle Display Name to English then tried to change to keep version 1.0 and change build versiyon to 1.2. Tried a lot of think and after 3 days surprise!!! Apple accept

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error. Solution I found was to change contents in "Name" section of app description in iTunes Connect.

There was no need to change app name to English language (as some suggest), **I just removed ":" character from app name** - and then I could submit it to review! My localized versions of application still contained non-English names.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem since my application name contains ":". The iTunes connect server returns 500 error because of it. I've just temporary removed ":" from English app title, submitted app and returned ":" back.

Answer (score 0):

I think it ended up being a combination of several factors, but one thing that was definitely wrong was that I hadn't clicked the box about posting info to the Korean store. This was off by default and needed to be clicked. After doing this and several version changes (ended up submitting 1.2 instead of 1.0!) my app finally went into "waiting for review...".

Comment: Just a comment: you don't have to increase the version number with each build and create unnecessary gaps. This is what the build number is here for. So you can have multiple uploads with version 1.0 for example and just increase the build number 1,2,3 etc. No problem.

Answer (score 0):

Tried all possible solutions Chrome and Safari; none of them worked.

Then I switched to Firefox and magically it went through.

Answer (score 0):

I found the simple solution. Just go to detail of the version, remove the current build then save.

Then click on the blue add button and add the current build again, save again. Then submit again.

It work for my case. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Log out from the iTunes from the current browser. and Login to iTunes from the another browser and try to submit the app.

Hope it works!

And Make sure that there should not be the Redundant binary (in other words the build number of the binary should not same).

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same problem.

Switching browsers to Chrome fixed it for me straight away, so will try clearing out Safari, and re-booting in order to get back to submitting with Safari.

@rayg - and for the sake of others - the Korean checkbox doesn't have to be checked in order to succeed in getting the app up for review. Maybe under certain circumstance it does have to be selected, so I'm not saying your solution to your scenario is wrong, but the post gave the impression that it's a requirement for every submitted app, which it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried above all recommended solutions but none of them worked for me . 
Then I select build version from my mac system and logged itunes connect using firefox from window system and it worked for me.
Or you can try itunes connect login from another Window/Mac system.